# Flex 4.6 hostComponent no longer Works?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, skinning, flex4.6

hostComponent seems to have stopped working as it used to before. If I create a custom comp based on lets say SkinnableContainer and apply default skin I am unable to see co hinting for Bindable/public variables from the skin. Code below to illustrate.

What am I missing here?  Same seems to happen with other components/skins. I'm using latest Flash Builder (4.6).

<--------- Component --------------->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                      width="400" height="300" skinClass="skins.testSkin">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]
            public var test:String = "Test";

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

<----------------- Skin -------------->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[         
            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                this.hostComponent
                // Push backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha directly.
                // Handle undefined backgroundColor by hiding the background object.
                if (isNaN(getStyle("backgroundColor")))
                {
                    background.visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    background.visible = true;
                    bgFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");
                    bgFill.alpha = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");
                }

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>        
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- Defines the appearance of the SkinnableContainer class's background. -->
    <s:Rect id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!--
        Note: setting the minimum size to 0 here so that changes to the host component's
        size will not be thwarted by this skin part's minimum size.   This is a compromise,
        more about it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21143
    -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:Group>

</s:Skin>
```

Comment: Your `[HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]` directive in the skin needs to specify the custom component (eg., `MyComponent`) and not merely the `SkinnableContainer` if you want to get code hinting on the vars and methods.  Is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: No typo, it was that simple :) I guess last time I used hostComponent I hand coded it... Why Does Flash Builder not add the custom hostComponent I wonder? And is there any use in having "[HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]" at all?          Thanks for the answer, add it as such and I will accept! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Flash Builder to be able to provide you with code hinting for the public methods and properties of a custom component, the custom component needs to be specified in the [HostComponent metadata directive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS8fdf84466d28f0b0-6fc09fae121f39ef56b-8000) within the skin.  Currently, the skin code you provided has:

```
[HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
```

Try changing that to whatever your custom component is, eg. `com.mydomain.MyComponent`.